# Window.Location Refreshes instead of Redirects

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a JQUERY function as follows

```
this.getURL = function()
{
    var name = getName();
    alert("Menu.aspx?name"+name);
    //window.location = "Menu.aspx?name"+name;
}
```

When I alert the URL I am attempting to go to, it is correct. However, when I call window.location on that string, the page just refreshes without going anywhere.

I have similar code where I have used window.location and it works. I typed in the url into my browser and it works as well.

At worst (even if the URL was wrong), I was hoping that it would just redirect me to some URL. However, I can't get it to do anything other than refresh the current page.

Also to clarify, the page which calls this function is not Menu.aspx

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The code you've posted is correct. The issue lies elsewhere.

Comment: check for console errors , window.location works exactly like you have it typed

Comment: @ScottSelby there's not console errors

Comment: @Snuffleupagus I tried both firefox and chrome, same problem

Comment: Does your current location end in a file extension or just a path? Navigate to [here](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1090190/snuffleupagus) and try to set a window.location with a relative path - it simply refreshes the page. If I go to a page that ends in a file extension relative paths seem to work fine.

Comment: My current location ends in a file extension. I tried navigation it still refreshes, I am currently looking at other areas of code, which may have caused this since there's a similar control, where I implemented the exact same thing and it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a relative path try setting `window.location.pathname`, otherwise set `window.location.href` for a full path.

You may also want to try `self.location.href`

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, it's been difficult to get redirects like this to work right. I've had to use `window.location.replace(<url>)`. If you're just changing an anchor tag, it's even more difficult. You have to do the following to get it to work in all browsers:

```
window.location.replace(<url>);
window.location=<url>;
window.open(<url>,'_self');
window.location.reload();
```