# FancyBox2 close parent iframe and afterClose parameter issues

Tags: php, jquery, fancybox-2

I am hoping someone can help me.

I have 3 pages, a register page which contains the call to load my second page in an iframe, which is a form which posts to a third page, which processing the registration.

What I am trying to do is set a session variable once the user has registered, and pass this back to the initial registration page.

The issue I am having is that when the third page closes, the afterclose on the first page is not firing?

RegisterPage.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function fancyboxTest(href,provider,providerid,username,email,location,firstname,surname) {
        $.fancybox({
            padding: 0,
            autoResize: true,
            autoSize: true,
            closeBtn:false,
            closeClick:false,
            afterClose  : function() {
               location.href = "home.php?se=<?php session['login'];?>";
            },
            modal:true,
            type: 'iframe',
            'href' : href + '?provider='+escape(provider)+'&providerid='+escape(providerid)+'&username='+escape(username)+'&email='+escape(email)+'&location='+escape(location)+'&firstname='+escape(firstname)+'&surname='+escape(surname)+''
        });
    }
</script>
```

Third Page

```
<?php
$_Session_start();
$provider = $_POST['provider'];
$providerID = $_POST['providerid'];
$username = $_POST['user_name'];
$email = $_POST['user_email'];
$forenames = $_POST['user_forename'];
$surname = $_POST['user_surname'];
$location = $_POST['user_location'];
$date =  date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$database = new Database();
$database->query('INSERT INTO users(provider, provider_id, name_forename, name_surname, name_username,registered_date) VALUES (:provider, :provider_id, :forename, :surname, :username,:datereg)');
$database->bind(':provider', $provider);
$database->bind(':provider_id', $providerID);
$database->bind(':forename', $forenames);
$database->bind(':surname', $surname);
$database->bind(':username', $username);
$database->bind(':datereg', $date);
$database->execute();
$nid = $database->lastInsertId();

$database = new Database();
$database->query('INSERT INTO profile(id, location, email) VALUES (:id, :location,  :email)');
$database->bind(':id', $nid);
$database->bind(':location', $location);
$database->bind(':email', $email);

$database->execute();

$tses = sha1($providerID . $date);
$_session['login'] = $tses;
$database = new database();
$database->query('UPDATE users SET session_id = :session WHERE id = :id');
$database->bind(':session', $_session['login']);
$database->bind(':id', $nid);
$database->execute();



?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    parent.$.fancybox.close();
</script>
```

Any idea on whats going on? The user is successfully registered and the iframe closes, however the browser sits at the register page? I have tried redirection just to home.php without any paremeters as I am not sure about the session being set yet, if I include a session_start on the register page I get a warning that it is already started.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/13317153/1055987 if that helps

Comment: Thanks for the link, no joy I am afraid, checking the console it looks like the window doesn't know that the third window has closed.

Comment: well, it supposes to perform when fancybox is closed, not any other window unless you are opening fancybox inside an iframe

Comment: My third window was still in a fancybox, it opened from window 1, window 2 was the form and window 3 was the form processing page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!

From form 3 this did the trick

```
<script type="text/javascript">
parent.jQuery.fancybox.close();
window.parent.location.href = 'home.php?se=<?php echo $tses;?>';
</script>
```